# C# UWP makes error when I'm trying to start process

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm developing UWP program that uses GPG executables.
I have below code that execute `gpg --list-keys` and get result

```
public class Gpg
{
    public void gpg()
    {
        Process compiler = new Process();
        compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "gpg";
        compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "--list-keys";
        compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        compiler.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

I also confirm that this code works fine in .NET Core console application.
But, as I use this code in UWP program. I got this error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: '{Illegal System DLL Relocation}
> The system DLL %hs was relocated in memory. The application will not run properly.
> The relocation occurred because the DLL %hs occupied an address range reserved for Windows system DLLs. The vendor supplying the DLL should be contacted for a new DLL'

I copied gpg.exe in UWP executable folder and downloaded GPG library for C#. But all libraries and tries make same error. I doubt if it's not able to start second process in UWP. Am I not able to do so? Or there's the way?

Comment: Wow, I have never seen that exception before

Comment: Can a UWP app even launch executables? hrmm, i thought not